# How to catch Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException in KNP Paginator?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

I don't want this kind of errors on the screen:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 66 near 'ewdd = :para': Error: Class
>   AppBundle\Entity\Ksiazka has no field or association named ewdd

How to catch Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException using KNP Paginator in my controller?

```
   $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a
        FROM AppBundle:Book a
        WHERE a.'.$findby.' = :param'
    )->setParameter('param', $what);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),45
    );
```